# Rotate in OpenGL

Tags: opengl-es

I'm confused with using the glRotatef function of OpenGL.

When I'm calling for this: `gl.glRotatef(90f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);` it rotates in Y direction of the object, like it's inverted?

Any explanation for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glRotatef` requires you to specify the normal to the plane you want it to rotate in. You've specified a normal of `x=1, y=0, z=0`, which specifies that you want the rotation to occur in the `yz` plane.

Comment: Thanks! That was fast! Will accept in eight minutes since this question was created recently. :)

Answer (score 2):

glRotateF lets you specify an vector which describes the central axis of your rotation. I.e. if you choose (1,0,0) you will rotate around the x axis and hence x coordinates will remain unchanged while y and z coordinates will migrate.